# Question on proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and got a little lost (it's just one detail). The proof uses the nested intervals property and it talks about chopping the interval into halves over and over. My question is: Why does one half of the intervals contain infinitely many terms of the sequence and the other half contain finitely many? Is it from the monotonic subsequence theorem that this follows?

Comment: Maybe. It would help to know what the theorem is.

Comment: If it is what I think it is (the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem's usual proof), then: **at least** one of the halves has infinite elements of the sequence, and this doesn' mean the other half has to have a finite number...

Comment: oops sorry it is Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Comment: Depends of what are your bases. For example the book that I've used prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem using characteristics of $\limsup$ and ensure this characteristic by the monotonic convergence principle and give us a cleaner proof. But in other books uses the same idea as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @DonAntonio said:

Assume there are only a finite number of sequence elements in one half of the interval. Then there must be an infinite number in the other half.

So in the context of the proof, you pick one half (doesn't matter which one). If it already has an infinite number of the sequence elements, move on to the next step. Otherwise, the other half has an infinite number of the sequence elements, so take that one instead. All we wanted to do is prove that at least one of the halves contains an infinite sub-sequence ... done.

Doing this step repeatedly lets you get infinite sub-sequences within smaller and smaller intervals. If, for example, we then choose an element from each of the intervals we obtain in this manner, we can derive an infinite sub-sequence that converges.

The statement you were taking in your question is actually not true (that one of them *has to* contain a finite number of sequence elements). Consider the bounded sequence: $$a_n=(-1)^n$$

When we perform our halving process the first time (starting with $[-1,1]$), both of the resulting intervals have an infinite number of sequence elements.

Comment: what is the point to obtain an infinite subsequence? Also misphrased what I was thinking. sorry for the confusion in the question.@Tim Seguine

Comment: Isn't Bolzano-Weierstrass: every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence? You need an infinite subsequence so that you don't run out of elements before you find a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Awesome! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: @user132771 Take a look at [Jose's](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/697908/15382) answer also. It shows a slightly different method to get the same result.

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to understand the other version of this proof. Thanks.@Tim Seguine

Comment: @user132771 always glad to help. If one of the answers particularly helped you, consider marking one of them as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to the one you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim says your statement is not true.

Here is an alternative proof.

Let call $n\in \mathbb{N}$ "nice" if $a_n >a_m$ for all $m> n$.

(1) Suppose that $(a_n)$ contain infinitely many "nice" points. In this case if $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_i< \ldots$ are the "nice" points, we have $a_{n_1}>a_{n_2}> \ldots>a_{n_i}> \ldots$, then $(a_{n_i})$ is a decreasing subsequence.

(2) The sequence contains finitely many "nice" points. Let $n_1$ be greater that all the "nice" points. Since $n_1$ is not "nice" there is a  $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2}\ge a_{n_1}$. Since $n_2$ is also not "nice", is greater than $n_1$ and for instance greater than all the "nice" points, there is a point $n_3>n_2$ such that $a_{n_3}\ge a_{n_2}$. Continuous in this manner, we obtain a non-decreasing subsequence $(a_{n_i})$

Then if the sequence is bounded we obtain a monotonic subsequence of $a_n$ which is bounded and then by the monotonic convergence principle must converge.

Comment: I like this method because you don't need the slightly technical epsilon-delta part necessary in my proof method.

Comment: Correct, and I understand this proof. However, I was trying to understand another proof that dealt with the Nested Intervals principle. Thank you.@Jose Antonio

Comment: @TimSeguine  this is my favorite: Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Since it is bounded then $c= \limsup  a_n$ is finite. Let define recursively the following sequence of natural number, $n_0=0$ and $n_i=\min(\{n> n_{i-1}:|a_n-c|\le 1/i\})$. Since $c$ is a limit point then the set is non-empty and the $\min$ is well-defined. Then $(a_{n_i})$ is a subsequence of $a_n$ and since $|a_{n_i}-c|\le 1/i$ for all $i\ge 1$ then the sequence converges to $c$, i.e., $(a_{n_i})\rightarrow c$. $\square$

Comment: @user132771: You're welcome. Try to see what you don't understand in the bisection method. But much depends of what are your basis if you assume least upper bound property, Cantor's nested inverteval, Cauchy completness, etc.